# Excel sumproduct in SAS

Tags: excel, sas

Table1

```
Age     B C D E F G H
0-10    5 6 8 9 0 1 1
10-20   4 5 9 7 1 4 5
20-30   5 6 5 4 2 5 8
0-10    0 4 0 5 8 0 7
```

Table2

```
Age      A1  B1  C1  D1
0-10     0.1 0.9 0.2 
10-20    0.5 0.6 0.7
```

I want to extract

```
SUMPRODUCT(Table1(G:H),Table2(B1:C1))
```

with condition that `IF Table1.Age = Table2.Age`.

OUTPUT Table should look like

```
AGE   SUMPRODUCT
0-10  0.8
10-20 0.70
```

Comment: Sorry prunts, The output is not exactly ouput of those tables. Just for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge the two datasets together, and then calculate the sum of the products.

```
data want;
merge table1(in=a) table2(in=b);
by age;
if a and b;
newvar = sum(g*b1, h*c1);
run;
```

You could do the same thing in a SQL join or a hash table lookup.

Arrays:

```
data want;
merge table1(in=a) table2(in=b);
by age;
if a and b;
array avars[20] <list of a vars>;
array bvars[20] <list of b vars>;
do _t = 1 to dim(avars);
   newvar = sum(newvar,avars[_t]*bvars[_t]);
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, But the variables are around 20 in each table, Some times I need to do for more then 2 tables. I thought of using Array statement but am not getting the values. Can you please explain by using ARRAY..

Comment: If you have two arrays of numbers, then just iterate through the joint array and accumulate in a sum variable.  Nothing special.

Comment: Thank you joe for your time and Will try it out.